# Block win10 to run more than a specified time / day

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

Using task scheduler I've been able to program my pc to shut down after 1 hour counting from log on

Is there a way to set up the pc, so that you can run the pc only a specified amount of time / day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Microsoft Account instead of a Local Account, and that way you can do this with the Microsoft Family Features that could be applied on a Child Account.

See some information how and what you can set, over [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12439/microsoft-account-set-child-limits)

For a local Account, there is no way to do it natively in Windows and you'll need a third-party software. One of the popular ones is [Time Boss](http://nicekit.com/parental-control-software.htm)